# How to make mysql run Delet query automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have an OTP table and I want to delete data that is older than 5 minutes automatically

Then how could I make trigger or procedure for that?

Comment: I would look into cron jobs, you don't really want this to be done via MySQL / I don't know if you can: https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Comment: Consider whether you really want to 'hard delete' data in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use according [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html) procedure.

```sql
CREATE EVENT remove_old_rows
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 10 SECOND
COMMENT 'Delete the rows that are older than 5 minutes from OTP table.'
DO
    DELETE 
    FROM OTP_database.OTP_table
    WHERE created_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Do not forget to enable Event Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it!  Just create view to get the most recent data:

```
create view v_otp as
    select otp.*
    from otp
    where otp.created_at >= now() - interval 5 minute;
```

Anyone who uses the view only sees the most recent data.

Then you can leisurely delete old data during a period when the database is not busy.

An added benefit is that this is always accurate.  If an event or job gets delayed, then your users might see old data.  Further, this does not involve complicated locking and transaction semantics when the server is busy.